# How to prevent web spider by identifing browser fingerprint?

Tags: javascript, security, web, web-crawler, fingerprinting

I know i can get usr's browser fingerprint by excute js script(canvas), but how to prevent web spider using a random fingerprint to crawl my website. how to identify a fingerprint is true or false ?? in the endpoint, i get the fingerprint is just a base64 string, it is easy to fake.

Comment: Your never going to be able to block a scraper if the programmer can successfully recreate a request the browser would make.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you won't be able to do this. This is user-controlled input, and user-controlled input can be faked by default.

Long answer:

1. First and foremost, there is no guarantee that a web spider will even run javascript code, so your fingerprint request will never come in in the first place.
2. For the sake of the argument, let's assume that it always does. The attacker can then run your fingerprinting code on a valid browser, and using a form of manipulation can force that script to produce different results (the one he wants). This would be the way to get the JS to run, while still faking the fingerprint.

In short, if you want to filter out bots, you have to rely on reCaptcha instead, which seems to be the most effective solution on the market.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i think attacker can use python script to call my API directly, if I want to identify the fingerprint string parsed from request post data. how can i do it ? can't i ? if i can identify the fingerprint, i will know the identity of caller.

Comment: Problem is - if user's browser can calculate the fingerpeint - so can the attacker without any problems. E.g. he can fire up the browser, get a valid fingerprint, and hook that up into his python script.
This leaves you with reCaptcha only, or API rate limiting.